# ReferencEerror can't find variable:image

Tags: react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{ StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
export default class Logo extends Component{
render(){
    return(
       <Image source={require('../images/stgi.jpg')} />
        )
}
}
```

1. simply just giving the image path it show error 
   how to fix it

Answer (score 14):

First of all note that if you are using react-native elements make sure you have been import it before using. To import Image try this

```
import {Image} from 'react-native' ;
```

Finally your code should look like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{ StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar , Image } from 'react-native';
export default class Logo extends Component{
render(){
    return(
       <Image source={require('../images/stgi.jpg')} />
        )
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you need to  Import Image from react-native.

```
import{
  Image, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View, 
  StatusBar } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import the library

`import { Image } from "react-native";`